# ruby image_tag printing entire record of image onscreen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I'm using Carrierwave to upload images to a Ruby app. This works fine in general; on one view, however, I'm getting the text of the record of the image on screen next to the image itself.

The relevant part of the view is:

```
  - if @impression.images.exists?
    = @impression.images.each do |pic|
    = link_to image_tag(pic.location.thumb.url), pic
    - if policy(pic).destroy?
      = link_to 'Delete Image', image_path(pic), :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Do you want to delete this image?'}
```

This is working fine, but the entire record of pic is printing out on screen next to the thumbnail image itself:

```
[#<Image id: 5, name: "Second image", location: "Kids.jpg", impression_id: 226, created_at: "2014-12-15 01:23:50", updated_at: "2014-12-15 01:23:50">]
```

It seems like there should be an obvious answer to this, but I just don't see it! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `=` with a `-` before `@impression.images.each do |pic|`. In ERB (and most other ruby templating languages), Ruby statements that begin with `=` will be added to the HTML output. In this instance, it is printing the array.